# Django external library and app name conflict

Tags: python, django, namespaces

Have a django app 'my_app'. Now added an external library that happens to have the same name and needs to be added to INSTALLED_APPS.

```
src
 |
 -- apps
      |
      --- **my_app**


external libraries
         |
          __ **my_app**
               |
                __some_path
                      |
                       __ new_module
```

Django follows the old path and spits out

```
Error: No module named my_app.some_path.new_module
```

because it is looking in the wrong folder.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    apps.my_app
    my_app.some_path.new_module
    ...
)
```

Note: order of apps in INSTALLED_APPS makes no difference. Removing apps.my_app from INSTALLED_APS also made no difference.

When I try to type

```
import my_app
```

pycharm auto suggests apps.my_app

Is there any way to resolve this without renaming one of the apps?

Answer (score 3):

Well, brace yourself for the upcoming Django 1.7 release which solves such app conflicts in an elegant manner using an ["app registry"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor). You can [set a label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#for-application-users) for each app to refer to them with a different name.